# How to create a form and keep the existing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actionview

I can link to the same page keeping the current params (except for the page param) with this

```
<%= link_to 'test', request.params.except(:page) %>
```

Is it possible to do this with a form? I thought this would work but it's not keeping the params

```
<%= form_with(path: request.params.except(:page), method: "get", local: true) do %>
```

this didn't work either

```
<%= form_with(path: params.except(:page), method: "get", local: true) do %>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have the the following search form which works great but I need to keep the current params `<%= form_with(path: request.fullpath, method: "get") do %><%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %><% end %>`

Comment: forms usually involve objects, which are usually reconstituted from parameters, so it appears you are trying to reinvent a wheel that doesn't need to be reinvented.  Why not just use form_with(object....) ?

Comment: could you let me know what you mean by form_with(object)? My Rails fu isn't strong enough to know where to go next with that

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to to pass params in the URL with a form. This feels a little hacky but the following works by sending the params as hidden fields. For example if you want to preserve params named "state" and "order" in your search form you can do this. This is safer than what I was trying above since it's explicitly whitelisting the params allowed (instead of removing the params you don't want, like "page" above)

```
<% request.params.slice("state", "order").each do |key, value| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag key, value %>
<% end %>
```